# How can I upload images to Picasso for my Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

In my app I want to make user to add their details and some images to save in FIREBASE database, I tried the below code to upload image, but when I upload another image it simply overrides the previous one. Then I got to  know that FIREBASE saves only URL for an image, but the problem is I am not able to save or cache the image in PICASSO.

```
private void uploadImage(){
    if(filePath!=null) {
        progressDialog.setTitle("file is uploading...");

        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child("databaseImages/image.jpg");

        riversRef.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        showToast("file uploaded");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        showToast(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage(((int)progress)+"% uploaded");
            }
        })
        ;
    }else{
        //display error toast
        showToast("please select an image.");
    }
}
```